# Left Outer Join with just one Match

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

First of all, a little explanation of my database. I am working in a warehouse and I've got a lot of palets, every palet contains some objects. The table of palets is called "pal", and the palet of objects is called "inv". Every "pal" has its own name, called "palid", and it is a primary key of the table "pal". Every "inv" has its own name called "invid" and the name of the palet where it is. They have more fields but there are not important for my question.

What I want is a SQL query that shows me every "pal" matched with all its "inv"'s but no repetition of "pal". Let me show you with an example:

**pal_1** contains **inv_1** and **inv_2**,

**pal_2** contains **inv_3**,

**pal_3** does not contain nothing.

I want this:

```
pal_1  inv_1
NULL   inv_2
pal_2  inv_3
pal_3  NULL
```

So I create this query:

```
select pal.palid, inv.palid
from pal right outer join inv on pal.palid=inv.palid
```

But I get this:

```
pal_1  inv_1
pal_1  inv_2
pal_2  inv_3
pal_3  NULL
```

And I don't want this repetition of pal_1 because I have like 1000 registers, and it is very difficult to know the state of my warehouse (if I have a lot of objects in my palets or not) without having this blanks on my query.

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: The standard/classic approach is to do this kind of formatting on the client, not on the server, using whatever report generation tool you are using.

Comment: Sorry is not MySql, is Microsoft Sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done in the presentation layer. However, if you really need it to be done in the database side, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.palid ORDER BY(i.invid)) = 1
            THEN p.palid
        ELSE ''
    END AS palid,
    i.invid 
FROM pal p
LEFT JOIN inv i
    ON i.palid = p.palid
ORDER BY p.palid, i.invid
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks Felix!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get such result

```
pal_1  inv_1

NULL   inv_2
```

You can get something about you need this way:

```sql
select pal.palid, group_concat(inv.palid)
from pal
left join inv on pal.palid=inv.palid
group by 1
```

So you get

```sql
pal_1 inv_1,inv_2
pal_2 inv_3
pal_3 NULL
```

Comment: sorry is not mySql but microsoft Sql, it is still working?

Comment: I don't know Microsoft SQL has this feature or not.

Comment: Vladimir Baranov has give you proper advise